# How to open new tab in Selenium 3 in java

Tags: java, selenium3

Before tagging this as duplicate. Please read the Question. i have seen many answers for this kind of question. But none of them really worked.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/driver/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

this my code. When I run this instead of opening a new tab its just opening in Current tab.How can i open second link in new tab?

Comment: you need new tab or window /

Comment: i need a new tab

Comment: then u can use my code

Comment: I don't want to use JavascriptExecutor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript for this in ur selenium code :-

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
 js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');");
```

Comment: yes this worked fine. But i don't want to use JavaScript. Is there any other way.

Comment: works fine then u can accept this ans so other can use this !

Comment: selenium also call JavaScript only indirectly .

Comment: This method was helpful for me in the browser headless scenario.